# Tween Engine, how to move object in one direction indefinitely

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using Java Universal Tween Engine https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/ with LibGdx to move my camera upward in an arcade game.
Problem is, *Tween.to* has a finite target value so it ends when it reaches that particular height.
What I've tried so far:

1. Using repeat method

   cameraTween = Tween.to(ArcadeScreen.stage.getCamera(), 0, 120).target(1000);
   cameraTween.repeat(Tween.INFINITY, 0);
   cameraTween.start(tweenManager);

This however, takes the camera back to zero and repeats

2. Using callbacks to extend target distance and call tween.start

   ```
       cameraTween.setCallback(new TweenCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onEvent(int arg0, BaseTween<?> arg1) {
               if (arg0 == TweenCallback.COMPLETED) {
               cameraTween.targetRelative(0, 1000);
               cameraTween.start(tweenManager);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

This approach didn't do anything. I used log statements and verified the callback was being called. The start method for some reason just isn't called the second time for some reason.

I would appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong in my above listed attempts and/or point me in the right direction as to how something like this should be done. Moving a subject in one direction indefinitely should be a pretty simple task. I just feel I've overlooked something basic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind if i ask why add a whole new lib just to move a camera up?

Comment: @Kush the game framework I'm using will require me to manage the camera's position every frame. Much easier to set a  Tween and forget about it